# Как запустить в виртуальной машине приложения на wpf

Tags: wpf, framework, windowsinstaller

Помогите, пожалуйста, запустить приложения без установки .NET Framework.

Вот ошибка, которую я получаю:

> To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework:
>    v4.0.30319
>   Contact your application publisher for instructions about obtaining the appropriate version of the .NET Framework.

Это вообще возможно сделать или нет?

Например:

Когда программа инсталлируется, она никогда не качает .NET Framework. В этом и состоит моя задача: как добавить его в проект? Пожалуйста, подскажите.

Comment: Translate, please.

Comment: Вы хотите добавить в папку с программой дистрибутив .NET чтобы он устанавливался перед установкой программы (с использованием инталлятора) ? или вы просто хотите что-то запустить на виртуальной машине? последние строки вашего вопроса слабо согласуются с заголовком

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете добавить установочный `.msi` файл в ваш проект в **Visual Studio**.

Вот тут инструкция пошаговая (На английском, но с подробными картинками) [Как добавить проект установки в решение и добавить инсталятор дотнета](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6090929).

Comment: Як додати установщик .msi в microsoft visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то. Нельзя запустить .net-приложение без установки .net frameworks. Единственное, что вы можете сделать, так это включить инсталлятор .Net в своей проект